# High vulnerability : Missing Origin Validation in Package webpack-dev-server, Dependency of react-scripts

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts

I already spent one whole day trying to fix this issue. I try to keep the description short.

- Working on Express-Mongo-React web app(MERN)
- Everything is working properly in local system.
- I have referred [this tutorial to host my project in AWS server](https://medium.com/@Keithweaver_/setting-up-mern-stack-on-aws-ec2-6dc599be4737) (Dev Mode)
- I have 'Client' folder where i keep all my react code.
- After uploading code in server, I run 'npm install'
- All the dependencies are installed properly except one.

  i.e. React-scripts

I see this error message after installing this react-scripts package

*'found 1 high severity vulnerabilit*y'

```
'npm audit' gives following summary


High         : Missing Origin Validation 
Package      : webpack-dev-server   
Patched in   :  >=3.1.11 
Dependency of: react-scripts
```

I restarted AWS instance, started everything from scratch. Nothing helped.

What could be the root cause?

Comment: I think a fix for this should be out soon. You can follow on Github https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6109